How can I best use dismissSearch and isSearching in my search view?
I'm playing around with a search view where I use search scopes and search suggestions. For the search suggestions I want to check if the search is active and dismiss the search when a suggestion is tapped to stop displaying the keyboard. To do so I want to use isSearching() and dismissSearch() but those can only be used from a child view. Making a child view would mean passing the search text, search scopes, selected search scope and search suggestions all as input to the child view (as a @Binding). That can be simplified by making a SearchModel which holds those values and passing that to the child view.
It feels cumbersome to have to make all that data available in the search view and its child view. Is this the best/only way or is there a better way to do this?
This is a simple representation of how the search view currently looks.
struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var searchScopes = [SearchScope]()
    @State private var searchScope: SearchScope?
    @State private var searchSuggestions = [SearchSuggestion]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .searchScopes($searchScope, activation: .onSearchPresentation, {
            ForEach(searchScopes) { scope in
                Text(scope.label).tag(scope)
            }
        })
        .searchSuggestions({
            ForEach(searchSuggestions, id: \.self) { suggestion in
                Button("\(suggestion.label)") {
                    searchScope = searchScopes.first(where: { $0.label == suggestion.label })
                    searchText = suggestion.value

                    // I don't call the runSearch() method because the onSubmit triggers for some reason which calls the runSearch()...
                }
            }
        })
        .onSubmit(of: .search, runSearch)
        .onChange(of: searchScope) {
            Task {
                await runSearchSuggestions()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: searchText) {
            Task {
                await runSearchSuggestions()
            }
        }
        .task {
            self.searchScopes = await httpClient.fetchSearchScopes()
            if !searchScopes.isEmpty {
                self.searchScope = searchScopes[0]
            }
        }
    }
}

Making a child view so dismissSearch() and isSearching can be used would look something like this.
struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var searchScopes = [SearchScope]()
    @State private var searchScope: SearchScope?
    @State private var searchSuggestions = [SearchSuggestion]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Searching for \(searchText)")
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText)
        .searchScopes($searchScope, activation: .onSearchPresentation, {
            ForEach(searchScopes) { scope in
                Text(scope.label).tag(scope)
            }
        })
        .searchSuggestions({
            ForEach(searchSuggestions, id: \.self) { suggestion in
                SearchSuggestionButton(suggestion: suggestion)
            }
        })
        .onSubmit(of: .search, runSearch)
        .onChange(of: searchScope) {
            Task {
                await runSearchSuggestions()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: searchText) {
            Task {
                await runSearchSuggestions()
            }
        }
        .task {
            self.searchScopes = await httpClient.fetchSearchScopes()
            if !searchScopes.isEmpty {
                self.searchScope = searchScopes[0]
            }
        }
    }

    func runSearch() {
        // preform search
        searchText = ""
        searchSuggestions = []
    }
}

struct SearchSuggestionButton: View {
    @Environment(\.dismissSearch) private var dismissSearch

    var suggestion: SearchSuggestion

    @Binding var searchText: String
    @Binding var searchScopes: [SearchScope]
    @Binding var searchScope: SearchScope?

    var body: some View {
        Button("\(suggestion.label)") {
            searchScope = searchScopes.first(where: { $0.label == suggestion.label })
            searchText = suggestion.value

            // I don't call the runSearch() method because the onSubmit triggers for some reason which calls the runSearch()...
            runSearch()
            dismissSearch()
        }
    }

    // Duplication of the runSearch() method
    func runSearch() {
        // preform search
        searchText = ""
        searchSuggestions = []
    }
}


Why would the child view need all those bindings? Its job is just to call dismissSearch, right? You have not included the child view that you mentioned in your current code. Please [edit] your question to include it.
